# BigCommerce Stencil Theme- Custom JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am looking to change my BigCommerce theme from Blueprint to Stencil and need to know if I can add custom JavaScript to the code for things like Woopra, Analytics and AdWords. If I can add it, how would I go about doing this once I get the new theme?

Comment: You can do it in the same way you did it in blueprint. You can download your theme, add the js, and reupload. Alternatively, you can use the google analytics box in the control panel or the footer scripts box.

Answer (score 0):

When you update to stencil, the backend will change slightly. Click on "Storefront Design" and it will take you to the "Design Options" page. There will be a tab called "Scripts" where you can upload any js without having to download and re-upload the theme.

Comment: Thanks! So far my scripts have been working once I added them in there.

Comment: if my answer helped would you be so kind as to "upvote" my answer. I'm trying to increase my reputation here. Thank you! :)